# Is There A Difference Between Search And Optimization?

Tags: algorithms

Is one a subset of the other? Two differentiable processes? The same thing?

In the textbook "AI: A Modern Approach", the terms seem to be used interchangeably.

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? Are you talking about search and optimization algorithms?